# Unable to jstat WebSphere Application Server PID

Tags: jvm, websphere

I've spent the entire day trying to find relevant resources about doing jstat on the WebSphere Process ID. I have WebSphere Application Server 7.0 installed on Windows 2003.

I did this command:
jstat -gcutil [PID] 1000

But I kept getting "[PID] not found" message.

Any idea how to resolve this issue? Or Java's jstat utility does not probe into IBM's derivative JVM?

Nicholas

Comment: I just edited the bkail's answer to include [Java Health Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21413628) which should be similar to jstat. Please accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sun jstat does not work with the IBM JVM. The equivalent method for IBM JVMs is to utilize the [Java Health Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21413628).